# Multiple inputs on one line using scanf

Tags: c++, input

I have written a program that will divide two numbers inputted by a user using "scanf" however, I want to change it so that it will allow the user to input for example "8/2" on one line, as oppose to inputting a number on two separate lines. This is giving me a lot of trouble and I think it may be because of the character "/" being used? Any help would be greatly appreciated, below is my original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    //defined variables
    float n1 = 0.0, n2 = 0.0, quotent = 0.0;
    int firstNumberRead = 0;
    int secondNumberRead = 0;
    //user inputs
    firstNumberRead = scanf("%f", &n1);
    secondNumberRead = scanf("%f", &n2);
    if (firstNumberRead && secondNumberRead == 1)
    {
        if (n2 == 0)
        {
            printf("invalid input - divide by zero not allowed");
        }
        if (n1 == 0)
        {
            printf("invalid input - divide by zero not allowed");
        }

        else
        {
            //divide the first number by the second number
            quotent = (n1 / n2);

            //print quotent
            printf("%f", quotent);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("invalid input");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `scanf("%f/%f", &n1, &n2)`

Comment: You're never doing anything to skip over the `/` character.

Comment: Awesome that works brilliantly. I appreciate the help :)

Comment: I've just got one more question mate. What would I do if I wanted to use whitespace inbetween the numbers and the division symbol for example: "8 / 2"? I tried to do this but I get the wrong output

Comment: `scanf()` is for C, you really should be using `std::cin` in C++. You can use `std::cin::operator>>` to read input values while ignoring whitespace between them.

Comment: @SeanCampbell Put spaces in the format string to match where you allow spaces in the input.